# SPARQL endpoint objects by URI based on 2 filters

Tags: sparql

I am trying to get URIs from the [British Museum database](https://collection.britishmuseum.org/sparql) for cylinders (object type) made of fired clay (material).
After testing the program on my own for a while with no results I got two suggestions from colleagues, however neither works.
Does anyone know how to successfully put in a query that does this?

```
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX crm: <http://erlangen-crm.org/current/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
SELECT ?object
WHERE {
  ?object crm:P2_has_type ?objecttype.
  ?objecttype skos:prefLabel "cylinder".                            
  ?object crm:P45_consists_of ?materialid.                    
  ?materialid skos:prefLabel "fired clay".
}
```

or

```
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX thes: <http://collection.britishmuseum.org/id/thesauri/>
PREFIX rso: <http://www.researchspace.org/ontology/>
SELECT ?cylinder
WHERE {
?cylinder rso:PX_object_type thes:x5597.
?fired_clay rso:PX_display_wrap thes:x41443.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example,

```sql
SELECT *
WHERE {
  ?object rso:Thing_has_type_Concept ?type .
  ?type skos:prefLabel "cylinder" .
  ?object rso:Thing_has_material_type_Concept ?material .
  ?material skos:prefLabel "fired clay" .
} LIMIT 100
```

or

```sql
SELECT *
WHERE {
  ?object rso:Thing_has_type_Concept thes:x6329 .
  ?object rso:Thing_has_material_type_Concept thes:x41443 .  
} LIMIT 100
```

---

In fact, there are many ways to do what you want, because there exist many synonymous properties.
Try this "metaquery":

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?type_property ?material_property
WHERE {
  VALUES (?object) {(<http://collection.britishmuseum.org/id/object/WCT20849>)}
  ?object ?type_property ?type .
  ?type skos:prefLabel "cylinder" .
  ?object ?material_property ?material .
  ?material skos:prefLabel "fired clay" .
}
```

---

As for the `rso:PX_display_wrap` property, it could be used in this way:

```sql
SELECT ?object
WHERE {
  ?object rso:PX_display_wrap "Object type :: cylinder ::" .
  ?object rso:PX_display_wrap "Consists of :: fired clay ::" .
}
```